# How to click a button on a webpage?

Tags: internet-explorer, button, autoit

A button on a certain webpage is like this.

```
<input ng-disabled="form.$invalid" type="submit" value="Log On" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right" />
```

How do I click it using AutoIt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved my issue.

I came up with something similar to the above poster.

```
$oLinks = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")
For $oLink In $oLinks
    If String($oLink.type) = "submit" And String($oLink.value) = "Log On" Then
          _IEAction($oLink, "click")
          ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$oTags= _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE,'input') 
For $oTag in $oTags 
    If $oTag.GetAttribute('type')='submit' Then     
        $oTag.click() 
    EndIf 
Next
```

This should work..